# How to access IIS 8 default site outside of domain network?

Tags: domain, iis-8

Our web server 2012 R2 has a static IP address on our domain network and site is on IIS  - can be accessed only if client is on the domain network via LAN or VPN. Cannot be accessed via internet. This is our GIS server and IT says it should be accessible from the internet by using IP address or computer/domain name. Probably obvious I'm a GIS guy and not that familiar with web servers etc. but we need this thing to work through the regular internet, and under the gun for a state-wide training session. Thanks, cob

Comment: Hi can I ask what IP addressing are you using?

Comment: You should ask the IT guys to create a server/firewall rule for redirecting traffic from your public IP to your internal GIS server IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a computer on a private network from the internet unless you utilize Network Address Translation such that incoming requests from the outside world are mapped to the server in question.

Your network admin/network engineer needs to help you.  He or she will probably assign a public IP address on a firewall at your company and translate that to the private IP address that is currently configured on the server.  If necessary, then you can create public DNS records (i.e. gis.mycompany.com) that point to the public IP address for easy access from the web.